# Issue to obtain SAMLResponse in a .NET FRAMEWORK application (SHIBBOLETH linked)

Tags: asp.net, saml-2.0, shibboleth

I have an ASP .net Framework web app, run on IIS, which uses SAML authentication through Shibboleth. Thanks to Chrome dev tools I see that something tagged as POST is received and the Token I need is inside this. But when I try to grab the value of this token to my app, the value is null / empty.

Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong and what I should do to grab de token value?

Thanks.

I have tried:

***string Token = Request.Form["SAMLResponse"];***

and also:

***string Token;***
***using (StreamReader Lector = new StreamReader(Request.InputStream)) { Token = Lector.ReadToEnd(); }***

But in both cases the value of Token is null or empty.

I must clarify that when I test the app in localhost then the token does have value ***Request.Form["SAMLResponse"].***